# Need to Join multiple tables in pyspark:

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

query using:

```
df= (df1.alias('a')
     .join(df2, a.id == df2.id, how='inner')
     .select('a.*').alias('b')
     .join(df3, b.id == df3.id, how='inner'))
```

error: name 'b' is not defined.

Comment: Try: `df=df1.alias('a').join(df2,on="id", how='inner').select('a.*').alias('b').join(df3,on="id",how='inner')`

Comment: Thank you Pault !! it worked.. Also could you please tell me the mistake in my query.. thanks in advance for that too?

Comment: As @9000 said below, it's because the call to `alias` does not create a python object. But these aliases *can* be used in spark-sql expressions.

Answer (score 1):

`.alias('b')` does not create a Python identifier named `b`. It sets an internal name of the returned dataframe. Your `a.id` is likely *not* the thing you expect it to be, too, but is something defined previously.

I can't remember a nice way to access the newly created DF by name right in the expression. I'd go with an intermediate identifier:

```
df_joined = df1.join(df1.id == df2.id, how='inner')
result_df = dj_joined.join(df_joined.id == df3.id, how='inner')
```

Comment: To access the newly created DF, I believe you can do something like `df = df1.alias('a').join(df2.alias('df2'),on="a.id=df2.id", how='inner').select('a.*').alias('b').join(df3.alias('df3'),on="b.id=df3.id",how='inner')`

Comment: Yes, you can call it by name in the string expression. You cannot access it in a proper Python expression, because the returned object is not yet bound to any name.